# How to Change Black Screen to Image While WKWebView is Hidden

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am keeping my WKWebView hidden while it is loading. But, while it is hidden it just shows me a black screen.

I have tried connecting an image view from the main.storyboard and showing it while the WKWebView was hidden. But, this gives me a thread 1 fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        logoImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mijnmedicijn") //error
        logoImageView.isHidden = false //error
        webView.isHidden = true
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.mijnmedicijn.nl/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)

    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress" {
            print(Float(webView.estimatedProgress))
            if Float(webView.estimatedProgress) == 1 {
                webView.isHidden = false
                logoImageView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Why does this not work? How would I cover up the black screen and show the image? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to combine storyboard code then

```
override func loadView() {
  super.loadView()  // <<<< call this
```

Comment: Now it gives me the same error (finds nil while unwrapping an optional) on this line of code: `logoImageView.isHidden = true`. The previous error is gone though.

Comment: can you try to add the webview also inside storyboard and link it instead of overriding `loadView`

Answer (score 0):

In the line 
`logoImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mijnmedicijn") //error`

You should have an image resource with the name `"mijnmedicijn"` in your project (app bundle) else it will crash.

I tried your code as is with a valid resource and it successfully ran as expected in your question. But when I gave an invalid resource name (i.e. name of a resource that didn't exist in my project) then crash was observed.